# CM3 does not boot. ACT stays solid green

Tags: boot-issues, image, compute-module-3

I've got a CM3 module which is working perfectly, and I received my second CM3 last week and I've been trying to clone the first to the second with no luck.

I start with the first CM3 and ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install rpi-update
sudo rpi-update
```

reboot

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

after reboot. And the first one still works. Then I put the first one into my CMIO3 and make an image using

```
sudo ./rpiboot
sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdb of=cm3.img
```

Wait a couple of minutes until the image creation finishes and switch the modules off, disconnect and connect the second CM3 module. Write the img to the second module

```
sudo ./rpiboot
sudo dd bs=4M if=cm3.img of=/dev/sdb
```

After dd finishes I disconnect the USB slave cable, disconnect and reconnect power cable and both POWER and ACTION LEDs stay solid red and green respectively.

Using Raspbian Jessie. Kernel 4.9.33-v7+

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/31880/sd-card-rpi-2-why-the-sd-card-wont-work). Sometimes I have to run a `sync` command after using `dd` to flash the card correctly, other times not. It's worth a try.

Comment: @stevieb : Nope, `sync` command after `dd` to eMMC of second CM3 module made no difference. I know the CM3 module works as when I write a new Raspbian lite image of 20170410 to the module it boots with no problem,  but it does not want to boot with my older version which I update and upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cloning the image, try imaging the CM3 module with the fast, painless method I documented at following link:

[How do I Flash (install) Raspbian on Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3 / 3+?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96032/how-do-i-flash-install-raspbian-on-raspberry-pi-compute-module-3-3/96033#96033)

Since this method is proven to image a CM3/3+ correctly, your CM3 should boot.  If it doesn't, then the shape of the problem is something other than how it was imaged.  HTH-